# How to use FileTemplate instead of Splice that has been superseded?

Tags: interoperability, latex

Having invoked `Splice[main.mtex]`,

```tex
% main.mtex

\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% <* f[x_] := x^2 - 5 x +6 *>
\begin{document}
\section{Problem}
Evaluate $ <* f[x] *> $ for $x=\frac 1 2$.

\section{Solution}
$$ <* f[1/2] *> $$

\end{document}
```

we have `main.tex`

% main.mtex

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% \text{Null}
\begin{document}
\section{Problem}
Evaluate $ x^2-5 x+6 $ for $x=\frac 1 2$.

\section{Solution}
$$ \frac{15}{4} $$

\end{document}
```

that will produce the following output when compiled with `pdflatex`.

[image]

## Question

How to use `FileTemplate` instead of `Splice` that has been superseded by `FileTemplate`?

Comment: Oops, yes, I realize that now. Your post came through the review queue, and I neglected to look carefully before posting the boilerplate greeting.  Nonetheless, welcome to the site! :)

Comment: for completeness you should include the expression for `f` in the question. I never used splice but I`m puzzled how you ended up with a decimal from exact input.

Comment: @george2079: You should try it first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the *essential* equivalent of `Splice` is:

```
 FileTemplateApply[FileTemplate["main.mtxt"], "main.txt"]
```

which produces:

> ```
>  % main.mtex
> \documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
> \usepackage{amsmath}
> % Null
> \begin{document}
> \section{Problem}
> Evaluate $ Plus[6, Times[-5, x], Power[x, 2]] $ for $x=\frac 1 2$.
> \section{Solution}
> $$ 3.75 $$
> \end{document}
> ```

evidently its applying `FullForm` to the first expression and `CForm` to the numeric result, while `Splice` seems to use `CForm` for both.

this seems to fix the formatting:

```
FileTemplateApply[
 FileTemplate["main.mtxt", 
  InsertionFunction -> (ToString[InputForm[#]] &)],"main.txt"]
```

> ```
>  % main.mtex
> \documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
> \usepackage{amsmath}
> % Null
> \begin{document}
> \section{Problem}
> Evaluate $ 6 - 5*x + x^2 $ for $x=\frac 1 2$.
> \section{Solution}
> $$ 15/4 $$
> \end{document}
> ```

better yet..

```
insert[v_Rational] := 
 TemplateApply[
  StringTemplate["\\frac{`1`}{`2`}"], {Numerator[v], Denominator[v]}]
insert[v_] := ToString[TraditionalForm[v]]
FileTemplateApply[FileTemplate["main.mtxt",
    InsertionFunction :> insert],"main.txt"]
```

> ```
> % main.mtex
> \documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
> \usepackage{amsmath}
> % Null
> \begin{document}
> \section{Problem}
> Evaluate $ x^2-5 x+6 $ for $x=\frac 1 2$.
> \section{Solution}
> $$ \frac{15}{4} $$
> \end{document}
> ```

Be aware `TraditionalForm` will have undesirable results if the output wants to be multi-line, `InputForm` is safer

Comment: An even better option would be to use `TeXForm` as in `insert[v_] := ToString[TeXForm[v]]`. This handles all special formatting associated with LaTeX and behaves, AFAIK, exactly the same as `Splice`.