# What is the contents of object.txt file used in the documentation of FileTemplate?

Tags: files-and-directories

I am trying to solve my previous problem posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123339/42141) but when reading [the documentation of `FileTemplate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileTemplate.html), I find unclear information about the file `object.txt` used in

```
t = FileTemplate["Examples/String/object.txt"]
```

What is the contents of this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `FileTemplate` by default has `Path -> $TemplatePath`, we should change `$Path` accordingly:

```
Block[{$Path = $TemplatePath}, FindFile["Examples/String/object.txt"]]
```

> ```
> "C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.4\SystemFiles\Components\Templating\Resources\TemplateLoader\Examples\String\object.txt"
> ```

```
FilePrint@%
```

> This is a `attribute` `object`.